# Is there a way to upload a image to a file in a already deployed app from app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

So I have to separate apps hosted at google cloud and I would like to know if it's possible from the app1 to send a file to a specific folder in app2. I tried to ssh into an instance but I can find anything.I'm new to google cloud so if anyone knows anything please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gcloud app instances scp` command. For more information about the command and how to use it, please see the link below:

```
[https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/instances/scp][1]
```